# Pandas Fill values from most recent dates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have two dataframes, and I want to add the values from the first dataframe to the second one based on the most recent date that was found.
Is there a built in method in pandas to do it?

Sample code:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'Time': pd.to_datetime(['1-1-2018', '1-1-2019']), 'Value':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'Time': pd.to_datetime(['1-23-2018', '1-22-2019'])} )
df3 = pd.DataFrame( {'Time': pd.to_datetime(['1-23-2018', '1-22-2019']), 'Value':[1,2]} )

display(df1)
display(df2)
print()
print('how to get df3 from df1 and df2?')
display(df3)
```

[image: output from sample code]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[merge_asof](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html) provides capability you want

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame( {'Time': pd.to_datetime(['1-1-2018', '1-1-2019']), 'Value':[1,2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame( {'Time': pd.to_datetime(['1-23-2018', '1-22-2019'])} )
pd.merge_asof(df2, df1, on="Time")
```

|  | Time | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2018-01-23 00:00:00 | 1 |
| 1 | 2019-01-22 00:00:00 | 2 |

Comment: Thanks! is there a way to run `merge_asof` per category?

Comment: I don't see any **category**. `merge_asof()` can only work on a single column.  A much more sophisticated approach is required is there are multiple columns involved in finding nearest